# Decrypting the Vigenere cipher ACTMEFPTQBFPLZRDPTQBFH

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

After finding all the bigrams, I concluded the key length has to be either 5 or 10, In the case of 5, the index of coincidence is a 0, while for 10 it's 1/225.

Which 1 is more likely to be the key? And how do I decrypt the cipher after that?

Answer (score 2):

You can see that PTQBF occurred twice and the two occurrences are separated by 10 elements, and assuming/using [Kasiski examiantion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher#Kasiski_examination) we can conclude the length of the cipher is factor of 10. But 1 and 2 are too short, so lets settle with 5 or 10. Next step is easy.Remember you can not be sure if it's 5 or 10 until you find the plan text,(one thing to assume is the plain text has clear English meaning) so you have to look for key assuming both cases.
Now we got the length, the problem becomes like Caesar's cipher and can be solved with frequency analysis as in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher#Frequency_analysis)

Final solution gives key of SPAIN and plain text INTERNATIONALRELATIONS.

Comment: it is not exactly becoming like Caesar cipher. It is harder than it. There are $26^5$ keys if the key length is 5. In Caesar cipher, it is fixed to 3. I shift cipher, that is a more general of Caesar cipher and it has 26 different keys.

Comment: We don't use frequency attack on Caesar cipher. We just use $C-3 \bmod 26$. If you consider the shift cipher than again just check the 26 key is enough. We apply the frequency attack to permutation cipher where the keyspace is $26!$  Now, you can apply the frequency attack to each sub-columns, and this is how actually the attack is performed after you find the key size. I'm wondering how does the frequency attack work in such a small ciphertext?

Comment: It is your post, you correct it yourself. I can check later.

Comment: @Babydesta are you sure that's the answer? INTERNATIONRELATIONS is not only awkwardly sounding, but also shorter by 2 digits than the cipher text, shouldnt it be international relations?

Comment: @Babydesta and even then, the key SPAIN doesnt give us such text, the 1st digit in the plaintext will have to be S for SPAIN to work (since the cipher starts with A which is the 0th alphabet)

Comment: @cryptoclownclass use [this site](https://www.dcode.fr/vigenere-cipher) with 5 as key length,

Comment: @cryptoclownclass, yes you are right it should be INTERNATIONALRELATIONS

Comment: @cryptoclownclass But SPAIN will give us the right answer.  I -> 9 and S -> 18, so I+S -> $9+18=27=1$ (that is adding with modulo 26) and A->1.

Comment: Just a methology question. Did you use some computerized brute force to find the key at the end? Frequency analysis helps you order the $26^5$ possible keys into more likely and less likely but with this kind of cypher length you would still have to test way more than you can test by hand.